# Select a limited number of relations (OneToMany) using TypeORM

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I would like to know the best way to select a fixed number of relations using TypeORM, for example if i have UsersEntity and PublicationsEntity, the user have more than 100 publications and i just want to select 10 of them, what is the best way to achieve that ?

Someone asked for something similar few years before but i haven't been able to do anything functional : https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/89

without any limit my code looks like this :

```
return await getRepository(UsersEntity)
        .createQueryBuilder('user')
        .where('user.userName = :userName', { userName })
        .leftJoinAndSelect('user.publications', 'publications')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('publications.category', 'category')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('publications.comments', 'comments')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('comments.children', 'children')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('publications.likes', 'likes')
        .getOne();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as they mention it on this topic with two queries, here's how:

```
const user = await getRepository(UsersEntity).createQueryBuilder('articles')
        .where("user.userName = :userName", { userName })
        .getOne()
    
   user.publications =   await getRepository(PublicationsEntity)
   .createQueryBuilder("publication")
  .where("publication.colmunuserid=:userId", { userId: user.id }) // replace colmunuserid with the correct name of the column 
    .leftJoinAndSelect('publication.category', 'category')
    .leftJoinAndSelect('publication.comments', 'comments')
    .leftJoinAndSelect('comments.children', 'children')
    .leftJoinAndSelect('publication.likes', 'likes')
  .limit(10)
   .getMany() 

 return user;
```

Comment: there is a difference of performance between this and subqueries ?

Comment: I think yeah a little bit, btw I'm working on a solution to do limit relation in one query, I'll update my answer and let you know whenever I got the new solution, til now this solution is working very well, good luck

Comment: If this is the ORM's solution then we should leave it.